# Angularjs Form action and getting errors back

Tags: php, angularjs, forms, file-upload

I have a form that I am using to get from the user a file to be uploaded to a server location. The form uses a 'action' to send the form to a PHP method (not going to the controller). The form information (i.e.: name) is then used to actually move the file within PHP methods.  If there is some error in moving the file, I want to return an error and show it to the user. I am having trouble trying to figure out how to display the message(s).

```
The form: 
  <form action="*/myobject/mymethod/uploadFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
      <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
      <p class="help-block">Upload a file to link.</p>
          <input type="text" name="myId" id="myId" value="{{theId}}" style="display:none;">
          <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File" class="btn btn-primary"> 
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload File 
          </button>
  </form>


My PHP method
public static uploadFile()
{
    there are calls to various methods that do the actual upload. These methods can return 
    errors if something caused the upload to not work properly. 

    If I want to return an error to display to the user do I:
       return "File did not upload";
    or
       return 'error';

    If no errors and all went well, I would like a message displayed to say it was successful.
}
```

What would be needed in the form and/or the PHP to allow me to display to the user a success/fail message?  Everything I found was on form validation, and this is not that but is a processing error/success checking.

Comment: What's the actual code that you've tried to accomplish this?

Comment: I tried the first return and have one for 'ok'; While it seemed to try to do the upload, I am thinking I got errors from the other methods I call to process the upload because the file wasn't moved/copied....but nothing displayed either...I am not sure how to process the 'return "ok" (or 'error') in the form.

Comment: It's not clear from what little code you're showing whether this is using a standard form submit or if it is being submitted via ajax.  If the former, then you need to redirect to the form page and either pass a parameter that indicates there was an error, or set a session value for that.  If the latter, then you should output a JSON string that includes the error data, and then parse that in your response handler.  Either way, doing a function `return` really isn't going to do you any good.  All that does is return a value to the caller of the function.  Regardless, your question is too broad